# Understanding このスマホ以外自宅

Tags: meaning

I was a playing a popular mobile game with someone. Unfortunately, he is unable to play with me today because of some urgent business matter:

> すみません、休日予定してたのですが出先で出勤依頼がありこのスマホ以外自宅です。

I don't get what このスマホ以外自宅 might mean. I think it means something like "at home, away from phone"?

Comment: Only commenting as I'm unsure — my take on this is that he is _super_ abbreviating his thoughts, leaving out stuff.  For 「スマホ以外自宅です」, I _think_ this might mean something like "other than my mobile, [all my other gaming devices are] at home."  But it's certainly not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- このスマホ
  this smartphone
- このスマホ[以外](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96)
  everything but this smartphone
- このスマホ以外(は)自宅です。
  Everything but this smartphone is at home.

By "everything but this smartphone", he is referring to his PC or game console. Note that, in Japanese, it's perfectly fine to make a sentence like 彼女はフランスです ("She is *in* France" rather than "She is France").